# Smoothstep sigmoid-like function: Can anyone prove this relation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

The [Smoothstep sigmoid-like function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep#Generalization_of_higher-order_equations) is defined as the polynomial

$$ \begin{align}
\operatorname{S}_N(x) &= x^{N+1} \sum_{n=0}^{N} \binom{N+n}{n} \binom{2N+1}{N-n} (-x)^{n} \qquad N \in \mathbb{Z} \ge 0 \\
                      &= \sum_{n=0}^{N}  (-1)^n \binom{N+n}{n} \binom{2N+1}{N-n} x^{N+n+1} \\
                      &= \sum_{n=0}^{N}        \binom{-N-1}{n} \binom{2N+1}{N-n} x^{N+n+1} \\
\end{align} $$

The first 7 examples are:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{S}_0(x) &= x \\
\operatorname{S}_1(x) &= -2x^3 + 3x^2 \\
\operatorname{S}_2(x) &= 6x^5 - 15x^4 + 10x^3 \\
\operatorname{S}_3(x) &= -20x^7 + 70x^6 - 84x^5 + 35x^4 \\
\operatorname{S}_4(x) &= 70x^9 - 315x^8 + 540x^7 - 420x^6 + 126x^5 \\
\operatorname{S}_5(x) &= -252x^{11} + 1386x^{10} - 3080x^9 + 3465x^8 - 1980x^7 + 462x^6 \\
\operatorname{S}_6(x) &= 924x^{13} - 6006x^{12} + 16380x^{11} - 24024x^{10} + 20020x^9 - 9009x^8 + 1716x^7 \\
\\
\end{align} $$

It is purported, for all non-negative integer $N$, that $\operatorname{S}_N(0) = 0$ and $\operatorname{S}_N(1) = 1$ and, *at those two points*, as many derivatives equal zero as possible.  I think it is also purported that $\operatorname{S}_N(\tfrac12) = \tfrac12$ and that this polynomial display odd-symmetry about the point at $x=\tfrac12$

If we define a linearly-scaled and offset version of the Smoothstep polynomial as:

$$ \operatorname{R}_N(x) = 2\operatorname{S}_N\left( \tfrac12(x+1) \right) - 1  $$

Then this means that $\operatorname{R}_N(-1) = -1$, $\operatorname{R}_N(1) = 1$, and as many derivatives as possible at those two points are zero.  And we see that $\operatorname{R}_N(0) = 0$ and that  odd-symmetry exists: $\operatorname{R}_N(-x) = -\operatorname{R}_N(x)$

Can anyone show, with the least amount of pain possible, that the derivative of $\operatorname{R}_N(x)$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{R}^{'}_{N}(x) &= \operatorname{S}^{'}_{N}\left( \tfrac12(x+1) \right)  \\
&= \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n! (N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \right)^{-1} (1-x^2)^{N} \qquad ? \\
\end{align}$$

This is not homework (I haven't been in skool since the early '80s). [This DSP question and answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/monotonic-symmetrical-soft-clipping-polynomial) show the previous work I have done with this.  It's just a little bit bitchy and I am not sure the least painful way to go about doing this.

I guess that I am trying to show that

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{S}^{'}_{N}\left( \tfrac12(x+1) \right) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n}(N+n+1) \left(\tfrac12(x+1)\right)^{N+n}  \\
&= \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \right)^{-1} (1-x^2)^{N} \\
\end{align}$$

This really looks like a copulating female canine to me.

---

EDIT:

Here is the **clearest** way for me to state the question:

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}, \ N \ge 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Define:

$$\begin{align}
 f_N & \triangleq \int\limits_{0}^{1} \big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} \ du \\
     & = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \binom{N}{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \\
\end{align}$$

Define:

$$ \operatorname{R}_N(x) \triangleq \frac{1}{f_N} \int\limits_{0}^{x} \big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} \ du $$

Define from the [Wikipedia definition of the Smoothstep sigmoid-like function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep#Generalization_of_higher-order_equations):

$$\operatorname{S}_N(x) \triangleq \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n} x^{N+n+1} $$

Prove:

$$ \operatorname{R}_N(x) = 2\operatorname{S}_N\big(\tfrac12 (x+1) \big) - 1 $$

It suffices to prove that their first derivatives of the left-hand and right-hand sides are equal, because we know the left-hand and right-hand sides are equal at $x=-1$.  This means it is sufficient to show that:

$$ \frac{1}{f_N} (1-x^2)^{N} = \frac{d}{du}\,\operatorname{S}_N(u) \Bigg|_{u=\frac12 (x+1)} $$

or

$$ \frac{1}{f_N} (1-x^2)^{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n} (N+n+1) \left(\tfrac12(x+1)\right)^{N+n} $$

or, explicitly:

$$ \left( \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \binom{N}{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \right)^{-1} (1-x^2)^{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n} (N+n+1) \left(\tfrac12(x+1)\right)^{N+n} $$

Comment: Your question is to prove the identity $\mathrm{S}_N\left(1-x\right) = 1 - \mathrm{S}_N\left(x\right)$, right? (Proving that $\mathrm{S}_N\left(x\right)$ has its first $N-1$ derivatives at $0$ vanish is obvious; now, once the identity is proven, it will follow that the same holds for the first $N-1$ derivatives at $1$.)

Comment: no @darijgrinberg, not precisely. my question as stated is to prove this identity: $$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} = 2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{-N}{n}\binom{2N-1}{N-n-1} \big(\tfrac12(x+1)\big)^{N+n}-1$$ primarily.  but i am happy if this identity is proven: $$\frac{(1-x^2)^{N-1}}{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{N-1}{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{-N}{n}\binom{2N-1}{N-n-1} (N+n) \left(\tfrac12(x+1)\right)^{N+n-1} $$ but i am happy to get a UMN prof's help. ;-)

Comment: and @darijgrinberg, i understand your point to the extent that if  $$\operatorname{S}_N(1-x)=1-\operatorname{S}_N(x)$$ then it's true that $$ \operatorname{S}_N(\tfrac12-x)=1-\operatorname{S}_N(\tfrac12+x)$$ and that will show that $\operatorname{R}_N(-x)=-\operatorname{R}_N(x)$ which is an important property of my *odd-symmetric Smoothstep* derived independently.  i want to somehow make sure that the two polynomials have equivalent coefficients, when $x$ is correctly scaled and offset between the two definitions.

Comment: Some time back, I derived a more compact expression for generalized smoothstep: $$S_N(x)=x^{N+1}\sum_{j=0}^{N}\binom{N+j}{j}(1-x)^j$$ This more symmetric presentation should ease the task of proving properties about it.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician , i must confess that i am a little dubious of the equivalence.  your expression is much simpler, but i have some trouble seeing the equivalency.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician i am still working on trying to just show that your expression for $S_N(x)$ has the derivative that i expect.  do you still have your derivation?  could you post it here?

Comment: Yes, I am planning on posting something a little later. I hope you don't mind waiting a little.

Comment: no. i don't mind.  it's 2 years after the fact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> We want to show for $N\geq 0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\right.}&\color{blue}{\left.\binom{N}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)^{-1}(1-x^2)^N}\\
> &=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n}(N+n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n}}\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We start  with the   RHS and obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^N&\binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n}(N+n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N+n}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N+n+1}(N+n+1)\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n}\tag{2}\\
> &=(2N+1)\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N+n}{n}\binom{2N}{N+n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n}\tag{3}\\
> &=(2N+1)\binom{2N}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{m}\binom{m}{q}=\binom{p}{q}\binom{p-q}{m-q}$

> With (4) the    claim (1) boils down to show
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\right.}&\color{blue}{\left.\binom{N}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)^{-1}(1-x^2)^N}\\
> &=\color{blue}{(2N+1)\binom{2N}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n}}\tag{5}\\
> \end{align*}

**Intermezzo**:

We can find a closed formula for the denominator of the LHS. The following is valid:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{4^N}{2N+1}\binom{2N}{N}^{-1}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

A proof is given in the appendix.

> Using (6) and since  $(1-x^2)^N=(1-x)^N(1+x)^N$ the equation (5) can be  simplified to
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2^N}(1-x)^N
> =\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\binom{N}{n}(x+1)^{n}}
> \end{align*}
>
> Applying the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* to the RHS we finally get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\binom{N}{n}(x+1)^{n}&=\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}\left(-\frac{1+x}{2}\right)^{n}\\
> &=\left(1-\frac{1+x}{2}\right)^N\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^N}(1-x)^N
> \end{align*}
>
> and the claim (1) follows.

We now prove formula (6) following chapter I (problem section, problem 4 with solution) in *Combinatorial Identities* by John Riordan.

> **Appendix:** The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \qquad\qquad\sum_{n=0}^N\binom{N}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{4^N}{2N+1}\binom{2N}{N}^{-1}\qquad\qquad N\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain using the *[Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)* $\delta_{N,0}$ 
>   \begin{align*}
> f_N=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}&=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\left(1-\frac{2n}{2n+1}\right)\\
> &=\delta_{N,0}-\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\tag{7}\\
> &=\delta_{N,0}-2N\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}\tag{8}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (7) we apply $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.

> We also get
>   \begin{align*}
> f_N=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}
> &=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\left[\binom{N-1}{n}+\binom{N-1}{n-1}\right]\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
> &=f_{N-1}+\sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}\tag{9}\\
> \end{align*}

Adding (8) and $2N$ times (9) we get
\begin{align*}
\qquad\qquad(2N+1)f_N=2Nf_{N-1}+\delta_{N,0}\qquad\qquad N\geq 0\tag{10}
\end{align*}

> Iterating (10) we obtain with $f_0=1$ for $N>0$
>   \begin{align*}
> f_N&=\frac{2N}{2N+1}f_{N-1}=\frac{(2N)(2N-2)}{(2N+1)(2N-1)}f_{N-2}=\ldots\\
> &=\frac{(2N)!!}{(2N+1)!!}\\
> &=\frac{(2N)!!(2N)!!}{(2N+1)!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2N+1}\cdot\frac{2^{2N}N!N!}{(2N)!}\\
> &=\frac{4^N}{2N+1}\binom{2N}{N}^{-1}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (6) follows.

Here we use *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)*
\begin{align*}
(2N)!!&=(2N)(2N-2)\cdots4\cdot 2\\
(2N+1)!!&=(2N+1)(2N-1)\cdots 3\cdot 1\\
\end{align*}
and the formulae
\begin{align*}
(2N)!&=(2N)!!(2N-1)!!\\
(2N)!!&=2^NN!
\end{align*}

Comment: looks like we'll have a winner.  i totally approve of substituting $N-1$ with $N$ throughout.  in fact, [that is how i set it up originally in my DSP post about it](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/monotonic-symmetrical-soft-clipping-polynomial).  in that presentation there is an   $\operatorname{R}_0(x)$. the problem was that $\operatorname{S}_N(x)$ in the Wikipedia article was set up differently (they start with $\operatorname{S}_1(x)$) and i wanted to make the two more compatible.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Ok, I see. You might find table 174 (p. 174) of *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.matematica.net/portal/e-books/Graham%20-%20Knuth%20-%20Patashnik%20-%20%20Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf)* helpful.

Comment: i had to do some intermediate steps: $$ \left(\sum_{n=0}^N \binom{N}{n}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\right)^{-1}(1-x^2)^N = (2N+1)\binom{2N}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n} $$
$$ \left( \frac{4^N}{2N+1}\binom{2N}{N}^{-1} \right)^{-1}(1-x^2)^N = (2N+1)\binom{2N}{N}\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+1)\right)^{N+n} $$
$$ \frac{1}{4^N} \, (1-x^2)^N = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{N+n}}\binom{N}{n}(x+1)^{N+n} $$ since $1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$ can't we: $$ \frac{1}{2^N} \, (1-x)^N = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n}}\binom{N}{n}(x+1)^{n} $$
?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: With  respect  to your first  comment of the last triple: Good observation! This *drastically* simplifies the proof. :-)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)

Comment: [i had originally defined $N$ as you do here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/monotonic-symmetrical-soft-clipping-polynomial), but the dumb Wikipedia article wanted to start off with $\operatorname{S}_1$ rather than $\operatorname{S}_0$ and in the math.SE i wanted to be consistent with the Wikipedia definition. this [counting from 0 vs. counting from 1 debate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) is old but i think [Dijkstra has nailed it](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). i just like consistency wherever possible.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson:  Peter van der Linden cites in *[Expert C Programming, Deep C Secrets](https://www.amazon.com/Expert-Programming-Peter-van-Linden/dp/0131774298)* a saying from Stan Kelly-Bootle: Should array indices start at $0$ or $1$? My compromise of $0.5$ was rejected without, I  thought, proper consideration. :-)  Btw: We should remove obsolete comments in order to save space.

Comment: This looks like an anagram of a really nice proof, Markus, but I really wouldn't mind seeing it unscrambled :) For example, it took me a while to see that your (1), (2) and (3) seemingly refer to the equality of whatever-is-on-that-line to the right hand side (not to the left hand side). It is generally better to write proofs bottom-to-top unless it's really clear how you are proceeding.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Although I was baffled the first moment, you are right of course ... and *anagram of a really nice proof* is a really nice formulation. :-) I did some restructuring.

Comment: Nice work on the proof! Mine was much longer and used Vandermonde convolution.

Comment: oh geez, i know convolution, but i have to look up what *Vandermonde* convolution is.  i am going to try to maybe fix up the proof to have Eq. (6) spelled out, rather than simply accept its validity.  i think i have groked all of the other steps to the proof.

Comment: also, i am going to try to include this relationship of the Smoothstep to the odd-symmetry version (with $\int\limits_{0}^{x}(1-u^2)du$) in the Wikipedia article and make this all consistent with each other.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I've added a proof for Eq. (6). Btw: *Vandermonde convolution* --> see table 174 :-)

Comment: thanx.  i'll look it over later, but soon.  BTW, i have fixed the $N-1 \leftarrow N$ substitution here and in Wikipedia.  so far no one as reverted the change.  i will be cleaning that and the Sigmoid function and maybe the "Activation function" pages a little in the future.  with saturation, i think these Smoothsteps are Sigmoid functions.

Comment: it really seems to me that the use of the Kronecker delta in the proof of Eq. (6) is a little silly since it is just *not there* for $N>0$.  seems to me that the clearest is to simply show that $f_0=1$ and that $$ (2N+1) f_N = 2N f_{N-1} \quad N \ge 1$$.  as i grok this proof, I think I will rewrite it, **maybe** with factorials replacing `binom{}{}`s

Comment: I have an issue with Eq. (9), Markus: $$\begin{align}
f_N &=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\left[\binom{N-1}{n}+\binom{N-1}{n-1}\right]\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N (-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}+(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
& \ne \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
&=f_{N-1} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad + \ \sum_{n=1}^N(-1)^n\binom{N-1}{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+1}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The usage of the Kronecker delta is just a matter of convenience to reduce the number of separated cases which are to consider as in (7). Its generalisation are *[Iverson brackets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* which are also in use. Feel free to use it as you like. Note that binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $k>n$. So, the equation is correct, since we are adding zero only. But in your third line you should use brackets.

Comment: well, I only applied distributivity and there is no multiplication of a sum and the dummy variable $n$ extends all the way to the right.  before this problem, I didn't even know of definitions for $\binom{n}{k}$ for cases of negative $n$ or for cases where $k>n$.  I had only been aware of $$ \binom{n}{k} \triangleq \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$ there are a lotta *"new"* facts and theorems about the binomial coefficient that I was unaware of. .... oh, I see, $(n-k)! = \Gamma(n-k+1)$ which is infinite if $k>n$ and both are integers.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: A proper generalisation is also $\binom{\alpha}{k}:=\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)/k!$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Here we also have $\binom{n}{k}=0$ if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n<k$.

Comment: i have since found that out.  i knew that with integer $n$ that $$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2) ... (n-k+1)}{k!} $$, and with that expression $n$ need not be an integer, nor even real, for that expression to have meaning.  i didn't know until reading that Knuth et. al. book you pointed to that people were doing binomial coefficients for anything *other* than for non-negative integers $0\le k\le n$.  but i still don't see how you get $\binom{n}{k}=0$ for integers $0 \le n < k $ without knowledge that $\Gamma(n-k+1)\to \pm \infty$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: $\binom{3}{5}=\frac{3\cdot 2\cdot 1\cdot \color{blue}{0} \cdot (-1)}{5\cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}=0$

Comment: yup.  okay, i got it.  it's more fundamental than the gamma function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is shown the development of the odd-symmetric Smoothstep function:

$$\operatorname{R}_N(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1 & x < -1 \\
\frac{1}{f_N} \int\limits_{0}^{x} \big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} \ du \quad & -1 \le x \le 1 \\
+1 & 1 < x \\
\end{cases}$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}, \ N\ge0 \in \mathbb{Z},$ and $\tfrac{1}{f_N}$ is a scaling constant judiciously chosen so that $\operatorname{R}_N(x)$ is continuous and $\operatorname{R}_N(\pm 1) = \pm 1$.

$$ f_N = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} \ du $$

Since the integrand is positive for $|u| < 1$, this is a monotonic increasing function.  It is also clear that odd-symmetry prevails:

$$ \operatorname{R}_N(-x) = -\operatorname{R}_N(x)  \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \ N\ge0 \in \mathbb{Z} $$

This odd-symmetric Smoothstep function is, I believe, directly related to the [commonly-defined Smoothstep sigmoid-like function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep#Generalization_of_higher-order_equations) as

$$ \operatorname{R}_N(x) = 2\operatorname{S}_N\big(\tfrac12 (x+1) \big) -1 \qquad -\infty < x < +\infty $$

where

$$\operatorname{S}_N(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n} x^{N+n+1} \quad & 0 \le x \le 1 \\
1 & 1 < x \\
\end{cases}$$

for $x \in \mathbb{R}, \ N\ge0 \in \mathbb{Z}$ .  This relationship is what I want rigorously proven.  (Or, at least, a decent amount of rigor.)

For $|x| < 1$ the 1st derivative of $\operatorname{R}_N(x)$ is

$$ \operatorname{R}_N^{'}(x) = \tfrac{1}{f_N} \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N} $$

The 2nd derivative of $\operatorname{R}_N(x)$ is

$$ \operatorname{R}_N^{''}(x) = \tfrac{1}{f_N} N \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-1} (-2x)$$

The 3rd derivative of $\operatorname{R}_N(x)$ is

$$\begin{align}
 \operatorname{R}_N^{'''}(x) &= \tfrac{1}{f_N} N(N-1) \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-2} (-2x)^2 \ + \ \tfrac{1}{f_N} N \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-1} (-2) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{f_N} \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-2} \bigg( N(N-1)(-2x)^2 - 2N(1 - x^2)  \bigg) \\
\end{align}$$

and, for $n \ge 1$, the $n$th derivative is

$$ \operatorname{R}_N^{(n)}(x) = \tfrac{1}{f_N} \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-n+1} \, g_n(x) $$

where $g_n(x)$ is some ($n$-1)th order polynomial function of $x$ and is finite in value.  This can be proven inductively by considering the ($n$+1)th derivative:

$$\begin{align}
\\
\operatorname{R}_N^{(n+1)}(x) &= \tfrac{d}{dx} \Big( \operatorname{R}_N^{(n)}(x) \Big) \\
&= \tfrac{d}{dx} \Big(\tfrac{1}{f_N} \, \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-n+1} \, g_n(x)\Big) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{f_N}(N-n+1)\big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-n} (-2x) g_n(x) \, + \, \tfrac{1}{f_N} \big(1-x^2 \big)^{N-n+1}g'_n(x) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{f_N} \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-n} \Big( (N-n+1)(-2x) g_n(x) \, + \, (1-x^2) g'_n(x) \Big) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{f_N} \big(1 - x^2 \big)^{N-n} \, g_{n+1}(x) \\
\\
\end{align}$$

where $ g_{n+1}(x) = (N-n+1)(-2x) g_n(x) + (1-x^2) g'_n(x)  $ .

Because of differentiation, the order of polynomial $g'_n(x)$ is one less than the order of $g_n(x)$, but polynomial $(1-x^2)g'_n(x)$ is one order greater than $g_n(x)$ and so also is $(-2x) g_n(x)$.

When $x = \pm 1$, then the first $N$ derivatives are zero, 
$$ \operatorname{R}^{(n)}(x) \Bigg|_{x=\pm 1} = 0 \qquad \text{for } 1 \le n \le N $$
making this polynomial maximally flat at $x = \pm 1$.

The integrand is a binomial and can be expressed as a power series using binomial expansion:

$$\begin{align}
\big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} & = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \binom{N}{n} \big(-u^2\big)^n (1)^{N-n} \\
  & = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \big(-u^2\big)^n (1)^{N-n} \\
  & = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} (-1)^n u^{2n} \\
\end{align}$$

So the integral can be expressed as an integral of a power series:

$$\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{x} \big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} \ du & = \int\limits_{0}^{x} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} (-1)^n u^{2n} \ du \\
& = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} (-1)^n \int\limits_{0}^{x} u^{2n} \ du \\
& = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} u^{2n+1} \Bigg|_0^x \\
& = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n+1} \\
& = x \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \big(x^2 \big)^n \\
\end{align}$$

When $x = \pm 1$, we get

$$ \int\limits_{0}^{\pm 1} \big(1 - u^2 \big)^{N} \ du = \pm \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} $$

This makes the scaler $f_N$ to be

$$\begin{align}
 f_N &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \\
  &= \frac{4^N}{2N+1}\binom{2N}{N}^{-1} \\ 
  &= \frac{4^N \ (N!)^2}{(2N+1)!} \\ 
\end{align}$$

(the closed form is because of the Proof in the Appendix of the accepted answer here) and makes the odd-symmetric Smoothstep function to be:

$$ \operatorname{R}_N(x) = \frac{(2N+1)!}{4^N \ N!}  \ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!(N-n)!} x^{2n+1} $$

for $|x| \le 1$ .

The Smoothstep polynomials (without splicing to the $\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \pm 1$ saturated components) look like

[image]

I think the order $2N+1$ starts at 1 and goes to 9 (or $0 \le N \le 4$)

With the saturation attached, the Smoothstep sigmoid-like curves look like

[image]

The odd-symmetry Smoothstep function is continuous everywhere and all derivatives, up to the $N$th derivative, are continuous everywhere and the ($N$+1)th derivative and higher are continuous everywhere except where the constant saturation is spliced to the polynomial at $x = \pm 1$.

What I want to be able to prove is that the two definitions of these Smoothstep polynomials are equivalent, given the proper scaling and offset of $x$.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{R}_N(x) &= 2\operatorname{S}_N\big(\tfrac12(x+1)\big)-1 & -\infty < x < +\infty \\
\\
\frac{(2N+1)!}{4^N \ N!} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!(N-n)!} x^{2n+1} &= 2 \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n} \big(\tfrac12(x+1)\big)^{N+n+1} - 1 & -1 \le x \le 1 \\
\end{align}$$

Because it is not hard to show equality at $x=-1$, to show both sides as equivalent, it suffices to show their derivatives as equivalent (with the proper scaling and offset of $x$).  So it suffices to prove that

$$ \frac{(2N+1)!}{4^N \ (N!)^2} \big( 1-x^2 \big)^{N} = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \binom{-N-1}{n}\binom{2N+1}{N-n} (N+n+1) \left(\tfrac12(x+1)\right)^{N+n} $$

This is what the bounty was for.

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know how much this could help you.*

What it seems it that, using $$S_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \binom{-n}{i} \binom{2 n-1}{n-i-1} x^{n+i}=n \binom{2 n-1}{n-1} B_x(n,n)$$ where appears [the  incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function). $$S_n\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)=n \binom{2 n-1}{n-1} B_{\frac{x+1}{2}}(n,n)$$ $$R_n(x)=2 n \binom{2 n-1}{n-1} B_{\frac{x+1}{2}}(n,n)-1 $$ $$S^{'}_n\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }
  \, \Gamma (n)}\left(1-x^2\right)^{n-1} $$ $$R^{'}_n(x)=\frac{2  \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\,
   \Gamma (n)}\left(1-x^2\right)^{n-1}$$
I hope and wish no mistakes on my side.

Comment: thanks Claude.  i am wondering where we're getting the "$(1-x^2)^{n-1}$" expression for $\operatorname{S}^{'}_n(\cdot)$ from? $$ $$ and i don't see a subscript $x$ for the beta function in the reference you gave.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson. If we consider $B_{a x+b}(n,n)$, the derivative is $a (1-a x-b)^{n-1} (a x+b)^{n-1}$

Comment: hey Claude, thank you for your contribution.  please don't take it badly if i put some of my paltry reputation on a bounty for this.  i would really like to see a rigorously constructed answer.  and i also do not understand why i am off by a factor of two.  i have two polynomials of the same order, and with proper scaling on **both** $x$ and $y=S_n(x)$, i can map $0\le x\le 1$ and $0\le S_N(x)\le 1$ to $-1\le x\le 1$ and $-1\le 2S_N\left(\tfrac12(x+1)\right)-1\le 1$.

Comment: Claude, where is this relationship between the Smoothstep and the Incomplete Beta function documented? $$S_N(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{-N}{n} \binom{2N-1}{N-n-1} x^{N+n}=N \binom{2N-1}{N-1} B_x(N,N)$$ for $N$ = 1, 2, 3...